# Comparar dos archivos .txt usando if else en python

Tags: python

Quiero comparar dos archivos de textos en Python. Según el resultado (igual/deferente), debe continuar mediante un condicional. Buscando en Google encontré este código, pero no me devuelve nada (TRUE/FALSE).

```
import filecmp
filecmp.cmp('txt/nuevo.txt', 'txt/master.txt')
```

Comment: Era más sencillo de lo que pensaba. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿como hago para elegir que tu respuesta fué la solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente [`filecmp.cmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.cmp) retorna `True` si ambos ficheros son considerados iguales y `False` en caso contrario.

El problema es que simplemente no estas usando el retorno de la función en ningún momento. Puedes asignar el retorno a una variable:

```
iguales = filecmp.cmp('txt/nuevo.txt', 'txt/master.txt')
if iguales:
    print("Iguales")
else:
    print("Diferentes")
```

O usa la función directamente en el condicional:

```
if filecmp.cmp('txt/nuevo.txt', 'txt/master.txt'):
    print("Iguales")
else:
    print("Diferentes")
```

> **Nota:** `filecmp.cmp` tiene un tercer parámetro, **`shallow`** que por defecto es `True`. Si este argumento es `True` la comparación se hace enfrentando las salidas de [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat), lo cual es más rápido que comparar el contenido directamente y que por lo general va a ser suficiente. Si se le pasa con valor `False` si que se van a comparar los contenidos en sí de ambos ficheros.